# Why can't I scrape for specific information of this webpage? (with node.js and jQuery)

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I want to scrape for specific information about news from this website: https://24.hu/fn/gazdasag/2022/07/23/igy-lehet-olcsobb-a-maganorvos-az-egeszsegpenztarbol/

I'm working on creating a web crawler and I need the new's title and the content. I use node.js, javascript and jQuery. And I've also created tests for that and I can reach the title, but I can't get the context. Despite of the fact that I've tried the code in the console of the browser, and it works well there.

This would be the code in the console:
$('[data-io-article-url="https://24.hu/fn/gazdasag/2022/07/23/igy-lehet-olcsobb-a-maganorvos-az-egeszsegpenztarbol/"]').text().trim();

And I get the following answer:

> A pandémia az életünk számos területét befolyásolta, de talán semmit sem annyira közvetlenül, mint az orvoshoz járási szokásainkat. Az elmúlt két évben tanúi lehettünk annak, hogy a végletekig leterhelt állami egészségügyi rendszer egyre nehezebben bírja a betegek megfelelő ellátását. Ráadásul úgy tűnik, hogy a járványt még korántsem tudhatjuk magunk mögött.....

In my VS Code I saved the html of the webpage and created the following test:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const parser = require("../24Parser");

const newsPage1Html = fs.readFileSync("tests/html/test.html");

let parserResult;

beforeAll(() => {
    parserResult = parser(newsPage1Html, );
})

describe("parsing html news page correctly", () => {
    test("title", () => {
        expect(parserResult.title).toBe("Így lehet olcsóbb a magánorvos az egészségpénztárból");
    })
    test("content", () => {
         expect(parserResult.content).toBe("lskl");
    })
})
```

And my parser looks like this:

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

function parseAll(html, page) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    const title = $('[itemprop="headline"]').text().trim();
    
    //const content = $(`[data-io-article-url="${page}"]`).text().trim();
    const content = $('[data-io-article-url="https://24.hu/fn/gazdasag/2022/07/23/igy-lehet-olcsobb-a-maganorvos-az-egeszsegpenztarbol/"]').text().trim();

    return { title, content}
}

module.exports = parseAll;
```

So I use exactly the same code and I get nothing in case of the content. Why is that?

I would like to create it dynamic later, that's why the commented line.

Comment: Just a suggestion - It could be that the content is injected into the page by script after initial loading of the page. So you might need to wait for that to happen before trying to get the contents of the body.

Comment: That will never happen though because no Javascript runs here. The OP is using Cheerio only, not a headless browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check, if scrapping is not blocked on this site, or does it have limits for requests. Also, it can be helpful to use a puppeteer wich opens google chrome in headless mode and make scraping.